# Good practice regarding multiple package management systems

Tags: linux, package-management

Some programming languages come with their own package management system, for instance, in the case of R, the built-in `install.packages` command installs from the CRAN repository and deals with dependencies.

In parallel, OS come with their own package management systems, like the `apt` command for debian-based Linux distributions.

I had decided that it was better to use the distribution's package manager, in order to guarantee that everything on my system would be compatible (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31293955/1878788).

But soon came a day when I needed things that were not available this way. For instance, a bioinformatics program that was not packaged by my distribution would require some specific version of R. It happened that the program was available through a project named "bioconductor", whose goal was to provide R packages for bioinformatics, ensuring that packages would be compatible with one another (see https://www.bioconductor.org/install/#why-biocLite).

So I decided not to use my OS packaging management system for R, and install everything through the `biocLite` command provided by the bioconductor project.

This approach ran smoothly for some time, until I discovered that to maintain coherent, healthy and easily rebuildable bioinformatics ecosystems, some people had decided to use the conda package management system. This project, called "bioconda" provides not only R packages, but things from all sorts of languages, with the possibility to easily switch versions, and so on (see https://bioconda.github.io/).

I then decided to use this approach instead, and it ran smoothly until I needed an R package that was not provided by bioconda/conda. It is supposedly super easy, but my attempts at making a conda package failed, then I tried to install the package using the bioconductor way, and it failed again. I have the impression that somehow the wrong R installation was being used by the package building mechanisms. So I decided to erase my (still very young) conda installation and go back to my bioconductor ecosystem.

I'm wondering how long I will have to jump from one approach to another. Are there general good practice regarding how to deal with these multiple, interfering, and overlapping levels of package management ?

**Edit (14/09/2017)**: Yet another option I considered is to use alternative OS-level package managers, like [Guix](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/) or [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/).

Comment: Fedora Project has [guidelines for packaging R programs](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:R). R RPM packages in Fedora, RHEL and CentOS will generally follow these.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure what is available for R (heard about REnv), but for Python I've decided on the pragmatic approach that every user is responsible for their own Python environment with `pyenv` (same is true for Perl with `perlbrew` and Ruby with `RVM`). That way, users can create their own optimal environment for every project without my assistance (`pyenv` manages Python installations and then you can use `pip` to install modules local to that specific Python installation).

System packages are only used for system needs.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is better to use system package manager.
But if you are using modern languages, that evolve fast, stable distributives won't include new packages and versions. And not-so-popular packages can never be included in repositories.

So I'd say, the best way in that case is using language's built-in functions. If R-creators will create official tool for managing packages, it would be great, but using non-official tools is somewhat risky.